# Strange problem with Derivative and BoxForm`MakeDerivativeBoxes

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, boxes

All of the following three lines should produce the same output, but the third variant produces an error on output.

```
{Derivative[{1, 0}][f][x], Derivative[{0, 1}][f][x]}
(Derivative[#][f][x] &) /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
(Derivative[#][f][x] &) /@ (IdentityMatrix@2)
```

[image: third line produces error]

The tooltip for the resulting red boxes says

"An unknown box name {BoxForm`MakeDerivativeBoxes} was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression."

I don't understand why the third variant should not work or what that error indicates.

Maybe the following helps in diagnosing the problem: Copy-pasting that last line as Plain Text gives

```
{BoxForm`MakeDerivativeBoxes[
  Derivative[{1, 0}][$CellContext`f][$CellContext`x], StandardForm], 
 BoxForm`MakeDerivativeBoxes[
  Derivative[{0, 1}][$CellContext`f][$CellContext`x], StandardForm]}
```

and `` BoxForm`MakeDerivativeBoxes `` is rendered in blue, indicating that it is undefined.

This is Mathematica 10.2 on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Same on 10.0.2, win 10, 64 bit, and `DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]` exhibits the buggy behaviour too

Comment: Almost certainly a bug. If you `Trace` the last two expressions, it's basically doing identical things, but in the last case, it outputs the red boxes. This workaround works: `(Derivative[##
][f][x] &) @@@ IdentityMatrix[2]`.

Comment: I had no problem executing this in Mathematica 9, but I have the same problem in 10.4.

Comment: The error even happens with this simple case: `Derivative/@(IdentityMatrix@1)`. It also happens for `(Inactive[Derivative[#]]&)/@(IdentityMatrix@1)` but *not* for `Inactive[Derivative]/@(IdentityMatrix@1)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been filed and officially accepted as an issue:

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I was able to
>   reproduce the issue, and consequently, I filed a report with our
>   development team raising the issues and also shared your contact
>   information with them so you can be notified once the issue is
>   resolved. Thank you again for taking the time and bringing this issue
>   to our attention and helping us improve Mathematica.